# about vs/g++ with copy-constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, g++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to compile the code in Visual Studio (2008) and g++.
In vs2008 it's successful, but in g++ it reported error.
if add `const`,
`test(const test &source):a(source.a) {}`
g++ will compiled succeed.
I kown that `test aa = 2;` will create a  temporary object and call copy-constructor.
**temporary object cannot bind to a non-const reference**
so,why the vs2008 can compiled it succeed?

```
class test{  
public:  
    test():a(1) {}  
    test(int num):a(num) {}
    test(test &source):a(source.a) {}  
private:
    int a;
};

int main(){
    test aa = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS has a non-standard extension that allows it, unfortunately.

There's a compiler flag to disable extensions, but last I checked it also makes it impossible to use the standard library. Your best bet is to keep the Warning Level on 4 (though this particular situation gets no warning), and check your compilations with multiple compilers when possible.

Comment: There is no warning for this, unfortunately.  /Za will disable the nonstandard behavior, but /Za is not recommended for use.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Ah, you're right, even with `/Wall` (which is basically unusable anyway). It *does* warn with `test aa = test(2);`, which is what it should be generating, but alas not otherwise.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I find that vs don't call copy-constructor, it call the `test(int num)`.

Comment: @skeu: Yea, it incorrectly implements initialization of the form `T x = y;`. That's suppose to be equivalent to `T x = T(y);`, which a compiler can then optimize to `T x(y);`, but it has to do it *as if* it made the copy (i.e.: the copy-constructor must be accessible). VS does not do that, it just goes straight to `T x(y)` regardless.

Comment: @GManNickG： Thx. I use `/Od` to refuse the optimize,but it don't work well.

Comment: Technically, it's not a failure to check accessibility, it's a failure to correctly perform overload resolution to find a matching constructor in the first place.  In any case, this is one reason that I always use direct initialization, even when it means writing an absurd number of parentheses.